# How do I trigger a new login window for Spotify API

Tags: python, spotify, spotipy

I am developing an app that uses the Spotify API through spotipy (Python).

I have a working setup which I have used succesfully over the past few days. However today, I switched to another machine for development, and I had to login again. Sadly, I entered the wrong Spotify account. Now I get an error:

```
"User not registered in the Developer Dashboard"
```

I would like to re-trigger the loginwindow in my browser so I can login with the right account. However I am unsuccesful in doin so.

I read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68462105/how-do-you-change-user-in-the-python-spotify-api) which advises to clear the cache files. I did that, but this only triggers a new redirect uri, which I then must enter in the terminal after the prompt "Enter the URL you were redirected to". Sadly, I dont get a new loginwindow, so I cant change user.

What do I have to do to get access to a new login window?

Answer (score 0):

Found a helpful answer.. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24408444/how-to-logout-user-from-spotify-after-authorization-and-web-api-call-is-over) had a working solution for me. The key was adding `open_browser=True` / `show_dialog=True`, and using the logoff links provided in the post if you really want to force a logoff.